# how to delete from a table that shares the same primary key

Tags: database-design, plsql, oracle11g

Hi I have a little bit of a database design problem

The user needs to capture

Form, Length min,length max, width min,width max, gauge min,gauge max(this is simplified).
he is expected to enter the form and at **least** one part e.g. the form and length min and max. He may enter more than one part.

I get the feeling that I should not have 1 table. I was planning on creating a form, length, width and gauge table. The length, width and gauge table will have a foreign key to the form table and my dimensions table will [share the same primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046514/how-can-i-share-the-same-primary-key-across-two-tables) (I think this is a 1 to 1/0 relationship). This will allow me to have/ not have certain parts where needed and eliminate null entries. My first problem is, is this good database design? If I need to delete how can I delete without removing the relationship(in plsql)?

Comment: I think the best advice may depend on just how simplified a representation this is.

Comment: @DavidAldridge The form consists of 3 more columns to describe the metal and the dimension parts consists of1 more column for length it would be length length min and length max.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rows with a 1 to 0/1 relationship is the same as for a 1 to many relationship. You could define the FK with `on delete cascade` so deleting the parent automatically deletes the child, or else always delete the child first.

I'm not sure I understand your model well enough to advise whether the two-table approach is the right one here, but in general it's a perfectly good technique when a subset of columns might not apply.

I don't see a PL/SQL question though so perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I good database design starts with Normalization. Hope the below link expains it lucidly.

[Normalization](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Normalization)